# Can I run a VPN on a host machine through a VM to connect to Tor?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn

I thought I'd give a VPN a shot with Tor on top. I understand that you connect to your VPN provider first then Tor. I want to run the VPN client on my host machine and use the Tor browser to connect to Tor using the default NAT setting in VirtualBox.

Will this work?

Is it secure and private this way or should I install the VPN client on the Linux guest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Will this work?" Yes! I currently run the VPN with Windows 10 host and the
VM guest using the TOR browser. The set up is as you described. The connection over TOR browser and using VPN is how several articles I have researched have recommended, you do when using TOR. Good luck!